# Installing parmap using anaconda3

Tags: python, anaconda

I want to install parmap in anaconda3 for windows 64. If I try  `conda install -c marufr parmap`, I receive an error reporting a conflict between python 2.7 and python 3.6 which is the current python version of my anaconda3. Is there any way to solve this issue? This is the error that I am receiving:

> UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in conflict:
>
> -parmap->python 2.7*
>
> -python 3.6*

Comment: looks like that package only supports py27 https://anaconda.org/marufr/parmap/files

Comment: I guess so... I have no idea how to get it into work  :|

Comment: I might need to change the nevironement of my anaconda to python27 for this

Comment: if there's no alternative package that supports python3.6, yes I think so

Comment: I need parmap for python 36

Comment: this repo mentions it supports python3 https://github.com/zeehio/parmap

Comment: That's for Linux. I need it for windows 64.

Comment: @downshift thanks for your help anyways.

Comment: No problem, where does it say it's only for Linux? Python is os independent if there are no window API calls,so should work the same on Windows

Comment: I get packagenotfounderror if I use this:conda install -c zeehio parmap. I beleive it does not have win-64 packages.

Comment: I'm on Windows 64 and python 3.4 virtual-environment, `parmap` install and runs the [Advanced: Multiple parallel tasks running in parallel](https://github.com/zeehio/parmap#advanced-multiple-parallel-tasks-running-in-parallel) screenshot: https://i.imgur.com/AaVTw77.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen this a good deal since using Python 3.6. What I have found is that, after receiving this message for a pacakage, quite often using pip to install a package works just fine. As is this case here. I just tested on:

Python 3.6.3 :: Anaconda custom (x86_64)

```
pip install parmap
Collecting parmap
  Downloading parmap-1.5.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: parmap
Successfully installed parmap-1.5.1
```

I did notice that the files listed for parmap in marufr are all python 2.7 specific, which is likely causing your problem.

To be more clear about the error message you are seeing it is in fact a little misleading. For an example try (on Python 3.6) `conda install xlutils`. You will see a similar message:

> UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in conflict:
>
> -python 3.6*
>
> -xlutils -> python 2.6*

That seems to say xlutils is only available for 2.6*. But looking further into the problem with `conda info xlutils` you will see something different. I'm not including the entire readout as it includes all of the versions available, but the last entry is below.

```
xlutils 2.0.0 py35_0
--------------------
file name   : xlutils-2.0.0-py35_0.tar.bz2
name        : xlutils
version     : 2.0.0
build string: py35_0
build number: 0
channel     : defaults
size        : 70 KB
arch        : x86_64
date        : 2016-07-19
license     : MIT
md5         : d73edc0acad935f1835f34a00d6454f0
noarch      : None
platform    : darwin
url         : https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/osx-64/xlutils-2.0.0-py35_0.tar.bz2
dependencies:
    python 3.5*
    xlrd >=0.7.2
    xlwt >=0.7.4
```

Clearly this package is available for Python 3.5 despite the misleading message from `conda install`.You could repeat this with the parmap package (after adding the channel to your config with `conda config --add channels marufr`), but as I mentioned there is only the one version in that channel so it isn't a great example. To be fair, xlutils doesn't have a Python 3.6 specific version out yet, but the 3.5 version works in 3.6 and can be installed using `pip install xlutils`.

In general I believe the case is just that a handful of packages haven't had the required files added yet.

Answer (score 2):

*(parmap author here)*

I recently realized the conda packages where not set to be arch-independent and I was building only linux packages in my channel. This is the reason why it was not possible to install `parmap` with `conda install -c zeehio parmap` on windows.

Anyway, I added parmap to conda-forge, so now it is possible to:

```
conda install -c conda-forge parmap
```

Or

```
pip install parmap
```

Whatever option you like best.

parmap works with python2.7 and python3 (as of May 2019, tested on python 3.3 through 3.7) and it works on all platforms supported by multiprocessing (Windows, OSX, Linux included).